# is it possible to make replication between versions 9.1 and 9.3

Tags: postgresql, replication

all instructions lead to synchronize data folders from master server to slave. But it can not be done between major releases.

ps: general task is update master and slave server from 9.1 to 9.3

Comment: I don't know the right answer to this, but I believe you are in for a world of pain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are talking about.

If you're talking about [slony](http://slony.info/) replication, it is designed to replicate data across versions. I've replicated databases from 8.4 to 9.1. You must have running the same schema (regarding the replicated objects) on both servers already. Slony replicates tables and sequences very well, it has some stuff for replicating schema changes, but I prefer doing this out-of-band.

If you're talking about in-place upgrading your db server, I'd suggest reading the [fine documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/upgrading.html) and going from 9.1 to 9.2, then to 9.3 (just to be cautious)